# how to display event creation screen while adding event to the calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, calendar

I'm trying to implement a functionality where the user can add an event to their calendar in **Expo**. For that I'm using [expo-calendar](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/calendar/), which adds the event directly to their calendar. If I use Calendar.openEventInCalendar(id), (which only  works for Android), it opens the event, not the event creation dialog like the image I have mentioned below. Please help me with this issue, I want to know if there is any other package that provides this functionality other than expo-calendar that supports Expo.

I have also looked into the external libraries like [react-native-add-calendar-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-add-calendar-event) and [react-native-calendar-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-events)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU8yZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.